# Google authentication with php laravel

Tags: php, laravel, google-oauth

I am creating a php laravel application that requires google oauth to work. So I created the following function:

```
function auth(){
   $client = new Google_Client();
   $client->setClientId($client_id);
   $client->setClientSecret($client_secret);
   $client->setRedirectUri($redirect_uri);
   $client->addScope("https://www.googleapis.com/auth/adsense.readonly");
   $authUrl = $client->createAuthUrl();
   return "<a href=\"$authUrl\">Connect Me</a>";
}
```

Now I want to access this `$client` variable when the user comes back on my site. Since my `Session` becomes empty after the redirect, I can't use that. (maybe something to do with the response being in HTTPS).

The two options I have considered are:
1) Cookies
2) Making the redirect url have the session id as a param (not sure if this can work)

Is there any standard way to achieve this?

Comment: Sessions should work. How are you using them?

Comment: I do `Session::put('client', $client);` before returning `$authUrl`. On the other side, I do `$client = Session::get('client');` but this comes out to be empty. Could this be because my auth() function is served over http and the redirect response uri is a different url that comes over https?

Comment: There is a package "adamwathan/eloquent-oauth-l5" which handles also google oauth. If you dont want to use it maybe you find your answere here.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest taking a look at http://oauth2-client.thephpleague.com/

There are code samples on it and it gives you good understanding of what you will need to do.

Alternatively take a look at [Laravel's Socialite](http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/authentication#social-authentication)